# Cannot set propert of 'mark' to undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

This is a strange error because it would appear it is wrong, the error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'mark' of undefined
at /home/ubuntu/workspace/tests/app.js:194:36
at Layer.handle [as handle_request](/home/ubuntu/workspace/tests/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/home/ubuntu/workspace/tests/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
at Route.dispatch (/home/ubuntu/workspace/tests/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/tests/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /home/ubuntu/workspace/tests/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
at Function.process_params (/home/ubuntu/workspace/tests/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/home/ubuntu/workspace/tests/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at SessionStrategy.module.exports.strategy.pass (/home/ubuntu/workspace/tests/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:325:9)
at SessionStrategy.authenticate (/home/ubuntu/workspace/tests/node_modules/passport/lib/strategies/session.js:71:10)
at attempt (/home/ubuntu/workspace/tests/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:348:16)
at authenticate (/home/ubuntu/workspace/tests/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:349:7)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/tests/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/home/ubuntu/workspace/tests/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
at /home/ubuntu/workspace/tests/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (/home/ubuntu/workspace/tests/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
```

The code that creates this error is:

```
for(var i = 0;i < req.body.numOfMethods;i++)
{
    for(var x = 0;x< numOfParts[i];x++)
    {
        methodsArray[i][x].mark=parts[i][x].mark;
        methodsArray[i][x].content=parts[i][x].content;
    }
}
```

Yet when I run the code under this text

```
console.log("numOfParts[i] = "+numOfParts[0]);
console.log("numOfParts[i] = "+numOfParts[1]);
console.log("numOfMethods = "+req.body.numOfMethods);
for(var i = 0;i < req.body.numOfMethods;i++)
{
    for(var x = 0;x< numOfParts[i];x++)
    {
        console.log("i = "+i);
        console.log("x = "+x);
        console.log("parts[i][x].mark = "+parts[i][x].mark);
        console.log("parts[i][x].content = "+parts[i][x].content);
    }
}
```

It prints out:

```
numOfParts[i] = 3
numOfParts[i] = 2
numOfMethods = 2
i = 0
x = 0
parts[i][x].mark = 2
parts[i][x].content = test
i = 0
x = 1
parts[i][x].mark = 2
parts[i][x].content = test
i = 0
x = 2
parts[i][x].mark = 2
parts[i][x].content = test
i = 1
x = 0
parts[i][x].mark = 3
parts[i][x].content = test
i = 1
x = 1
parts[i][x].mark = 3
parts[i][x].content = test
```

Which very much shows that `methodsArray[i][x].mark` is not being set to an undefined value. So ultimately here I'm quite lost as to what I should do to fix this error.

Here is where I define the arrays in question (in case my error resides within this code)

```
var methodsArray=[[{mark:Number,content:String}]];
    var numOfParts=[req.body.m1parts,req.body.m2parts,req.body.m3parts,req.body.m4parts];
    var parts=[
        [
            {mark:req.body.m1p1mark,content:req.body.m1p1content},{mark:req.body.m1p2mark,content:req.body.m1p2content},
            {mark:req.body.m1p3mark,content:req.body.m1p3content},{mark:req.body.m1p4mark,content:req.body.m1p4content},
            {mark:req.body.m1p5mark,content:req.body.m1p5content},{mark:req.body.m1p6mark,content:req.body.m1p6content},
            {mark:req.body.m1p7mark,content:req.body.m1p7content},{mark:req.body.m1p8mark,content:req.body.m1p8content},
            {mark:req.body.m1p9mark,content:req.body.m1p9content},{mark:req.body.m1p10mark,content:req.body.m1p10content}
        ],
        [
            {mark:req.body.m2p1mark,content:req.body.m2p1content},{mark:req.body.m2p2mark,content:req.body.m2p2content},
            {mark:req.body.m2p3mark,content:req.body.m2p3content},{mark:req.body.m2p4mark,content:req.body.m2p4content},
            {mark:req.body.m2p5mark,content:req.body.m2p5content},{mark:req.body.m2p6mark,content:req.body.m2p6content},
            {mark:req.body.m2p7mark,content:req.body.m2p7content},{mark:req.body.m2p8mark,content:req.body.m2p8content},
            {mark:req.body.m2p9mark,content:req.body.m2p9content},{mark:req.body.m2p10mark,content:req.body.m2p10content}
        ],
        [
            {mark:req.body.m3p1mark,content:req.body.m3p1content},{mark:req.body.m3p2mark,content:req.body.m3p2content},
            {mark:req.body.m3p3mark,content:req.body.m3p3content},{mark:req.body.m3p4mark,content:req.body.m3p4content},
            {mark:req.body.m3p5mark,content:req.body.m3p5content},{mark:req.body.m3p6mark,content:req.body.m3p6content},
            {mark:req.body.m3p7mark,content:req.body.m3p7content},{mark:req.body.m3p8mark,content:req.body.m3p8content},
            {mark:req.body.m3p9mark,content:req.body.m3p9content},{mark:req.body.m3p10mark,content:req.body.m3p10content}
        ],
        [
            {mark:req.body.m4p1mark,content:req.body.m4p1content},{mark:req.body.m4p2mark,content:req.body.m4p2content},
            {mark:req.body.m4p3mark,content:req.body.m4p3content},{mark:req.body.m4p4mark,content:req.body.m4p4content},
            {mark:req.body.m4p5mark,content:req.body.m4p5content},{mark:req.body.m4p6mark,content:req.body.m4p6content},
            {mark:req.body.m4p7mark,content:req.body.m4p7content},{mark:req.body.m4p8mark,content:req.body.m4p8content},
            {mark:req.body.m4p9mark,content:req.body.m4p9content},{mark:req.body.m4p10mark,content:req.body.m4p10content}
        ]
    ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var methodsArray=[[{mark:Number,content:String}]];` this does not have anything except `methodsArray[0][0]`.

`methodsArray[i][x]` (or even `methodsArray[i]`) is `undefined` (except when `i===0` and `x===0` [except again for Array methods, e.g. `i===0` and `x==="push"` but that's off the point]).

As shown in your test output, your loop is accessing something other than `methodsArray[0][0]` and trying to set a property.

If you want you can create the elements on the go:

```
var methodsArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < req.body.numOfMethods; i++)
{
    methodsArray.push([]);
    for(var x = 0; x< numOfParts[i]; x++)
    {
        methodsArray.push({
          mark: parts[i][x].mark,
          content: parts[i][x].content
        });
    }
}
```

This is only to be done once though, when creating `methodsArray`.

As another note, i realized you are likely writing Typescript (or maybe Flow?). Type annotations do not use `=` but `:`, so it would need to be `var methodsArray:{mark:Number,content:String}[][];` or `var methodsArray:Array<Array<{ mark:number, content:string }>>;`. In Javascript, `var methodsArray=[[{ mark:number, content:string }]];` is an Array with one element, an Array with again one element which is an object, where the property `mark` is the `Number` constructor and `content` is the `String` constructor.

Comment: So to fix this problem I would need to do
    methodsArray[i][x].mark.push(parts[i][x].mark);
    methodsArray[i][x].content.push(parts[i][x].content);
Is that right?

Comment: No, your issue is that `methodsArray[i]` or `methodsArray[i][x]` is undefined, you cannot set properties on undefined. There is also no `push` on undefined. E.g. `methodsArray[1] === undefined` or `methodsArray[0][1] === undefined`. You are doing e.g. `methodsArray[1][0].mark` which translates to `undefined[0].mark` which doesnt work.

Comment: Okay so how would I define it or would I do it another way?

Comment: Your problem is the `methodsArray`, you are setting it to `[[{mark:Number,content:String}]];` but later using it as if there were more elements in the array. You need to either add all elements when you set `methodsArray` or create the elements on the go. I added example code to the answer. Also it looks like this is Typescript or maybe Flow or something?

Comment: How would I 'create the elements on the go' ?

Comment: See edited answer. But i am still confused about whether this is type annotation gone wrong or really the object you wrote for whatever reason.

Comment: Thank you allot for your help here.